# How can we sketch three dimentioan films with different thicknees?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I want to sketch this box-like configuration

[image]

I wanted to start writing codes but I have some default options. I need to complete it.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 



\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am looking for a specific code including proper colors and position, direction, ... for different films in the image.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, it is unclear to me what you want to achieve. If you want to get a representation of the image shown, you should describe it a bit better. It would also good to show code you tried to achieve the intended result (the code you show does not output anything actually). Maybe it becomes clearer then. Also, Ti*k*Z might not always be the best tool to draw realistic 3D diagrams with shadings, lightning effects and complex structures.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you for your message. Actually, I do not know how to start it. I tested many codes but none of them worked! Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions.

#### Try 2D first

In fact, it's much easier and the result can be just fine.

To start 2D, even sketch it on paper, first, e.g. on paper already providing some help lines.

`3D will require an artists view`, i.e. creating a 3D-illusion, for a fixed position/angle, taking into account perspective(s) (vanishing points), introducing color gradients, highlighting etc. A lot of work, which doesn' always pay-off once transfered to Tikz (though you can do almost all of it). The Tikz-3D approaches won't help you much today.

#### Consider creating the image with other tools instead

E.g. if you have access to a 3D drawing tool, like blender etc., draw it there, save as .pdf and use `\includegraphics` from package `graphicx`.

#### Use Tikz tutorials AND own attempts in parallel

There are many sources for this, like:

- [on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_1)%E2%80%94Basic_Drawing)
- dedicated short intros like from [Universität Leipzig](https://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/%7Ehellmund/LaTeX/pgf-tut.pdf)
- and please: spend several reads on the [excellent 4 tutorials in the pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/tutorial)
- to learn from others you may skim through the [Tikz gallery](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/all/) (which often shows code, which could be simplified)
- and, of course, search here, e.g. following the [tikz-pgf tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf)

Yes, it takes a while to tame this powerful beast. In hindsight you'll see, it's quite logical and consistent, with some hick-ups here and there.

It's always a good idea to note down a few tikz-commands, which are new for you, and look them up in the [pgf-manual](https://tikz.dev/); it's built from simple to in-depth, part by part. Learn by doing. Apply what you read or learned about.

#### Simple first tasks for you

To prepare for your drawing, you could set yourself a few tasks, which break down the drawing, like:

- drawing `one rectangle`
- modify its fill color `[fill=...]` and its outer color `[draw=...]`
- draw a `stack of rectangles`: white, brown, white, blue, gray, a different gray
- draw `one circle`
- apply the draw and fill `options`
- draw `several circles`
- `organise them` as a grid/matrix/whatever (see [tutorial in pgf-manual](https://tikz.dev/tutorial-chains))
- `join both`: you're almost done
- understand how to `draw lines` and use library `arrows.meta`
- if in doubt: `do less`, or `do it later` (with better knowlegde)

#### Finally ...

... a few first keywords you should understand with Tikz, wrt. your question:

- `\note`, `\draw`, `\path`
- `shape` circle of a node
- `formatting`, like [draw=green, fill=yellow]

As a graphic designer you'll use layers frequently to draw an image as you ask for. This allows to separate things, reduce unwanted interactions etc. Luckily Tikz offers a quite similar concept [Layererd Graphics](https://tikz.dev/base-layers#autosec-8362). Though it's quite late in the manual (quite-in-depth section), it's quite simple to understand and to apply.

Here's an example from me, using layers in `Paint.net` for a desgin study:

[image: layeredGraphics]

As a beginner you may want to draw layer contents first as separate `tikzpicture` s, and then move them gradually to pgflayers to show them all-at-once.

If in doubt, simplify your drawing. E.g. draw just a circle, and leave the fill-stuff for later, once you've acquired more routine with Tikz.